# JSON array Parsing issue in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I've got a JSON Request that I'm able to add to an NSDictionary but I'm unable to access part of the JSON string. Here is a sample

```
 {    
 "Resp": {
  "Success": "True",
  "who": {
      "userid": 234,
  },
  "students": [
    {
      "ID": 1,
      "name": John
    },
    {
      "ID": 2,
      "name": Jane
    }
  ],
}
}
```

I am storing the data in an NSMutableDictionary and then passing that to my function which should run through each student and process them accordingly.

Here is what I've got so far and it's not working:

```
-(void)foo:(NSMutableDictionary*)json {
  NSArray *students = json[@"students"];
  for(NSMutableDictionary *student in students) {
    NSLog(@"student id: %@", student[@"ID"]);
  }
}
```

When debugging I can see the JSON object and students belongs under Resp as a value.

Comment: So, why aren't you extracting the Resp element (which is the dictionary containing everything else)?  (Note that you failed to copy the opening `{` of the outer JSON "object".)

Comment: Go to json.org and make sure you understand the JSON syntax.  Note that a NSLog of NSArray/Dictionary objects looks ALMOST like the corresponding JSON, but some quotes are missing, `()` is used around arrays, `=` is used between key/value pairs.

Comment: Thanks, I had typed out the JSON data instead of copy+pasting it.
I think I am extracting the Resp element which contains everything else. While debugging I can see the Resp element and everything else inside the _NSDictionaryM object. My issue is perhaps my method to access the students array.

Comment: NSLog is your friend -- it shows you the JSON subset you've selected very nicely.  NSLog just about every step until you figure out what's going on.

Comment: Just replace NSArray *students = json[@"students"]; with NSArray *students = [json objectForKey:"students"]  and student[@"ID"] with [student objectForKey:"ID"], you need to read NSDictionary reference though

Comment: Solution: After having passed the json data to the function, I had to add the entire response to an array:

    NSArray *resp = json[@"Resp"];

Then, extract the students from the resp array:

    NSArray *students = [resp valueForKey:@"categories"];

This allowed me to then use the rest of my code above to do what I needed with the elements of the students array.

Comment: @Vacca what you're suggesting is a synonym of what he's already using.  Perhaps you should brush up on recent (2-3 years) changes in Obkective-C.

Comment: @rootit that's all well and good, but note that the type of `resp` in your solution should be NSDictionary, not NSArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check your JSON on the validity http://jsonlint.com . It corrected your JSON with next modifications:

```
{
    "Resp": {
        "Success": "True",
        "who": {
            "userid": 234
        },
        "students": [
            {
                "ID": 1,
                "name": "John"
            },
            {
                "ID": 2,
                "name": "Jane"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Then you should access your elements in right way:

```
- (void)foo:(NSMutableDictionary *)json {
    NSArray *students = json[@"Resp"][@"students"];
    for(NSDictionary *student in students) {
        NSLog(@"student id: %@", student[@"ID"]);
    }
}
```

For now it should be working.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My JSON was valid and I had checked it prior to creating this question. I should've mentioned that I was free typing the JSON rather than just copy+paste the valid response. I haven't tried your solution, however, I solved my own question as seen in my previous comment. My reputation is under 10 and was unable to answer my own question.